# Jquery code working on IE but not on Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I am using jQuery to create a pop up tool-tip in my jsp. There is a table with a different hyperlink in each row. When user hovers mouse over the hyperlink, I want the tooltip to be displayed and when user hovers away, I need it to fade away gradually.

I was able to achieve this using below code in IE, but when tried the same page on FF, it is showing a different behaviour. **It is actually publishing the content of the tooltip somewhere else on the page and not inside the tooltip box**, where it should have been. Also, not removing the content from page on hover away. Please help.

```
<style>             
#tooltip{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background:#f7f5d1;
    padding:2px 5px;
    color:#333;
    display:none;
    width: auto;
}   

/*  */
</style>            
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">            
    this.tooltip = function(){  
        /* CONFIG */        
        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 50;       
        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result     
        /* END CONFIG */

        $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){
            this.t = this.title;
            this.title = "";
            $(body).append("<p id='tooltip' class='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
            $("#tooltip")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
                .fadeIn("slow");        
        }, function(){
            this.title = this.t;        
            $("#tooltip").remove();
        }); 

        $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
            $("#tooltip")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
        });         
    };

    // starting the script on page load
    $(document).ready(function(){
        tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

The HTML portion generated by the JSP is:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px" >
    <tr valign="top" class="h1">
        <td>Version</td><td>Price</td><td>Published</td><td>Edition</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td><a href="http://botswana.blackwell.co.uk:82/jsp/display_product_info.jsp?isbn=9781857159042" class="tooltip" title="<table><tr><td><img class='jacket' width='75' border='1' alt='ISBN:9781857159042' src='/images/jackets/s/18/1857159047.jpg' /></td><td>ISBN: 9781857159042 <br>Version: Hardback <br>Price: &pound;10.99 <br>Publication Date:24 Sep 1992 <br>Publisher: Everyman Everyman's Library</td></tr></table> ">Hardback</a></td><td>&pound;10.99</td><td width=auto align=center>1992</td><td width=auto>New edition</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td><a href="http://botswana.blackwell.co.uk:82/jsp/display_product_info.jsp?isbn=9781840119688" class="tooltip" title="<table><tr><td><img class='jacket' width='75' border='1' alt='ISBN:9781840119688' src='/images/jackets/s/18/1840119683.jpg' /></td><td>ISBN: 9781840119688 <br>Version: Hardback <br>Price: &pound;16.99 <br>Publication Date:01 Sep 2009 <br>Publisher: Templar Publishing</td></tr></table> ">Hardback</a></td><td>&pound;16.99</td><td width=auto align=center>2009</td><td width=auto></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td><a href="http://botswana.blackwell.co.uk:82/jsp/display_product_info.jsp?isbn=9781841939735" class="tooltip" title="<table><tr><td><img class='jacket' width='75' border='1' alt='ISBN:9781841939735' src='/images/jackets/s/18/1841939730.jpg' /></td><td>ISBN: 9781841939735 <br>Version: Hardback <br>Price: &pound;14.99 <br>Publication Date:01 Sep 2011 <br>Publisher: Arcturus Publishing Ltd</td></tr></table> ">Hardback</a></td><td>&pound;14.99</td><td width=auto align=center>2011</td><td width=auto></td></tr><tr valign="top"><td><a href="http://botswana.blackwell.co.uk:82/jsp/display_product_info.jsp?isbn=9781853261183" class="tooltip" title="<table><tr><td><img class='jacket' width='75' border='1' alt='ISBN:9781853261183' src='/images/jackets/s/18/1853261181.jpg' /></td><td>ISBN: 9781853261183 <br>Version: Paperback <br>Price: &pound;1.99 <br>Publication Date:01 Sep 1993 <br>Publisher: Wordsworth Editions Ltd</td></tr></table> ">Paperback</a></td><td>&pound;1.99</td><td width=auto align=center>1993</td><td width=auto>New edition</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td><a href="http://botswana.blackwell.co.uk:82/jsp/display_product_info.jsp?isbn=9781840114881" class="tooltip" title="<table><tr><td><img class='jacket' width='75' border='1' alt='ISBN:9781840114881' src='/images/jackets/s/18/1840114886.jpg' /></td><td>ISBN: 9781840114881 <br>Version: Hardback <br>Price: &pound;14.99 <br>Publication Date:01 Oct 2008 <br>Publisher: Templar Publishing</td></tr></table> ">Hardback</a></td><td>&pound;14.99</td><td width=auto align=center>2008</td><td width=auto></td></tr><tr valign="top"><td><a href="http://botswana.blackwell.co.uk:82/jsp/display_product_info.jsp?isbn=9780141023557" class="tooltip" title="<table><tr><td><img class='jacket' width='75' border='1' alt='ISBN:9780141023557' src='/images/jackets/s/01/0141023554.jpg' /></td><td>ISBN: 9780141023557 <br>Version: Paperback <br>Price: &pound;4.99 <br>Publication Date:26 Jan 2006 <br>Publisher: Penguin Books Ltd Penguin Classics</td></tr></table> ">Paperback</a></td><td>&pound;4.99</td><td width=auto align=center>2006</td><td width=auto>New edition</td></tr><tr valign="top"><td><a href="http://botswana.blackwell.co.uk:82/jsp/display_product_info.jsp?isbn=9781848770010" class="tooltip" title="<table><tr><td><img class='jacket' width='75' border='1' alt='ISBN:9781848770010' src='/images/jackets/s/18/1848770014.jpg' /></td><td>ISBN: 9781848770010 <br>Version: Hardback <br>Price: &pound;14.99 <br>Publication Date:01 Sep 2010 <br>Publisher: Templar Publishing</td></tr></table> ">Hardback</a></td><td>&pound;14.99</td><td width=auto align=center>2010</td><td width=auto></td></tr><tr valign="top"><td><a href="http://botswana.blackwell.co.uk:82/jsp/display_product_info.jsp?isbn=9780956266828" class="tooltip" title="<table><tr><td><img class='jacket' width='75' border='1' alt='ISBN:9780956266828' src='/images/jackets/s/09/0956266827.jpg' /></td><td>ISBN: 9780956266828 <br>Version: Hardback <br>Price: &pound;6.99 <br>Publication Date:28 Oct 2010 <br>Publisher: White's Books Ltd</td></tr></table> ">Hardback</a></td><td>&pound;6.99</td><td width=auto align=center>2010</td><td width=auto></td></tr><tr valign="top"><td><a href="http://botswana.blackwell.co.uk:82/jsp/display_product_info.jsp?isbn=9781906814489" class="tooltip" title="<table><tr><td><img class='jacket' width='75' border='1' alt='ISBN:9781906814489' src='/images/jackets/s/19/1906814481.jpg' /></td><td>ISBN: 9781906814489 <br>Version: Paperback <br>Price: &pound;3.50 <br>Publication Date:02 Jul 2010 <br>Publisher: Classic Comic Store Ltd</td></tr></table> ">Paperback</a></td><td>&pound;3.50</td><td width=auto align=center>2010</td><td width=auto></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing some quotes here:

```
$('body').append("<p id='tooltip' class='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
```

I assume that `body` is defined per default in IE, but not in Firefox. By enclosing it in parenthesis you actually trigger the selector engine of jQuery to search for the element instead of trying to wrap the (non-existant) variable.

A somehow working example can be [found here](http://jsfiddle.net/RXYc7/). Yet your code doesn't seem to remove the "tooltip".

Comment: Thanks Sirko for the edit and looking into this. I tried quotes, but the problem is, I am still not able to achieve what I am getting in IE. The content which can be seen getting published on the bottom of the page is coming up as in a tooltip in IE, but FF is showing the behaviour similar to what the link to the working example is showing.

Comment: In IE, the content is populating as a tooltip inside a yellow box which pops up when user hovers and fades away as soon as user hovers out. The code is same.

Comment: @anshultiwari On which IE version is it working? My IE9 shows the same output as my Firefox does. So the code is generally flawed imo.

Comment: Yeah, mine is IE9 as well. The HTML code here is actually generated by a java class and passed to the jsp. Do you think that might make a difference?

Comment: @anshultiwari If it is the same resulting code as shown here, it should make no difference. On the other hand - why don't you use some tooltip plugin for jQuery?

Comment: I am new to jQuery and don't have much idea about the tooltip plugin for jQuery. Can you please guide me for using one, probably a simple one to start. I thought this was the simplest way to create a tooltip but not working out.

Comment: @anshultiwari Have a look at [jQuery UI - tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/). I think the "code" here is pretty self explaining.